# Whether text datatype in sql will support special characters?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Whether text datatype in sql will allow special characters ?
i couldnt get proper documentation/samples when i googled . Can anyone confirm me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you call a "special character" and your RDBMS.

On SQL Server, the `nvarchar` data type can store any unicode character (and uses twice as much space as `varchar`).